# Finding a list of functions in library in C

Tags: c, function

Is there a way of finding a list of functions of any library in c?

For example, i would like to find all functions of library string.h without looking it up online.

Comment: No, not for *any library*. Also, `string.h` is not a library. It is a header. Also this is very vague. What compiler, which operating system, *which library*?

Comment: Okay, my mistake, i did not know that, i am a begginer. I want to find list of all functions of string.h in c without searching for it online

Comment: Here's the [list in C11 standard draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). It is one document that you can download.

Comment: Just open and look inside `string.h` (OK, it's hard, but it answers question)

Comment: You find out which functions a library contains by reading its documentation. Which you must do anyway, in order to use those functions. Questions asking where to find documentation are off-topic here.

Comment: Read the header file. You have all the functions listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read it.

It generally doesn't have much stuff other than function declarations. If you want to be sure you don't miss any includes from `string.h` recursively, you can read the prepossessed result:

```
cc -E  -include string.h -x c /dev/null
```

However, note that `string.h` is not a library. It's just a header that provides the declarations for a subset of a standard libc library (a library that gets linked to every hosted C program by default).

Also, you should generally limit yourself to using those declarations in the header that are [standardized](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24) (in case some implementation declares any extras in its `string.h`), and to using them in a standard-sanctioned way.